# Edit  my message before posting in Twitter with Twitter API and PHP

Tags: php, post, twitter

I am having a site and I want to add a button in my site that will link to the twitter login page and after login it will post a message to the Twitter home page of the user.

I used this code:

http://www.matpal.com/2010/12/oauth-access-token-in-twitter-api.html

and it works fine. My problem is that before posting the message I want to be able to edit it.

So after login I want to see my message in an editing input (like retween do,here: http://www.mobilemarketer.com/cms/news/search/10263.html ) and post it after clicking Tweet.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to use OAauth for that. Simply use a link like: [http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=lol](http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=lol) If you're not logged in, you'll be prompted to and redirected.

Comment: I want to ask the users to login every time. Anyway the authentication works ok, my problem is the editing of the post.

Comment: So, you mean that each and every time a users logs in to Twitter via your site, a tweet should be posted to the timeline of the user that just logged in?

Comment: No, this is what the tutorial does, and works also ok for me. I want before posting in the timeline, to see my message in the editable input and then click tweet. I am not sure if this could happen. In the link I sent before, the example, it does exactly what I want. But as title it says Retweet and I don΄t know if something like this has to do with Retweet or is something I different.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a [HTML form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) that submits a POST request back to a PHP file on your site. In that page you will extract the [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variable, validate it, then use it to post a new status like `$connection->post('statues/update', array('status' => $newStatusTextFromPost));`